# Background Image AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to put image(menumain) as fullscreen background. My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@drawable/menumain"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainavatarbck">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/mainavatar"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainnamebck">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="7dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/mainname"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/maincity"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mainname"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainbackbtn">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:tint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:id="@+id/mainbackicon"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/MainContainer">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

There is problem because image is not on full screen. There is 'blank' around (image is on center). What should I do for solve this problem?

Actually I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/menumain"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    //info
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainavatarbck">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/mainavatar"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainnamebck">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="7dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/mainname"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/maincity"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mainname"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainbackbtn">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:tint="#FFFFFF"
                        android:id="@+id/mainbackicon"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        //koniec info
        //kontener
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/MainContainer">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        //koniec kontenera
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set ImageView background

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: In my code is: android:background="@drawable/menumain"

Comment: try android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I tird to implement Imageview and use scaleType but there is another problem, I have only this imageview (still not on full screen), I edited my post. Could you check it?

Comment: Can you place the imageView below first linear layout and use match_parent as width and height

Comment: Then you need to set it as RelativeLayout to set other views on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Is it linearlayouts attribute?

Comment: it is ImageViews atrribute

Comment: @littlewombat no, it's `ImageView`'s attribute. If you want to set drawable as layout background, better trim it yourself. However, you can use `FrameLayout`, and put an `ImageView` in the center of it with `scaleType="fitXY"`.

Comment: Check my code (I edited my post) Actually there is only photo and it is still not full screen

Comment: @littlewombat if the photo has blank space itself, you can't do anything actually

Comment: There is not blank space in the photo, blank space is in the screen (because photo is not on full screen)